# Postgresql jsonb query optimization query not using index

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, indexing, jsonb

table with jsonb datatype column

| id | json_data(jsonb) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "CorrelationId": "1111", "References": [ { "Id": "001", "Type": "RefType" }, { "Id": "002", "Type": "RefType" } ] } |
| 2 | { "CorrelationId": "2222", "References": [ { "Id": "001", "Type": "RefType" }, { "Id": "003", "Type": "RefType" } ] } |

My query below is not using the index hence performing very slow:

```
select * from refs
where json_data -> 'References' @> any(array(select jsonb_build_array(refNo) from jsonb_array_elements(cast('[{"Id":"001","Type":"RefType"},{"Id":"002","Type":"RefType"}]' as jsonb)) refNo))
```

GIN Index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON refs USING gin ((json_data -> 'References') jsonb_path_ops);
```

Whereas below query performing well and using the GIN index but problem with this query it wont result row 2 so the expectation is I want to result all rows contains any/ all matching "RefType" so in this case I expect the query to return both rows in the result though row 2 is not having  **"Id": "002"**

```
select * from refs
where json_data -> 'References' @> '[{"Id":"001","Type":"RefType"},{"Id":"002","Type":"RefType"}]'
```

Edited:

Query plan for the query in the question:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Gather  (cost=1001.25..1135454.32 rows=2490762 width=486) (actual time=23804.717..23807.660 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                    |
  Output: 
  Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
  Params Evaluated: $0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
  Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
  Buffers: shared hit=4220 read=609812 dirtied=75                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=61795.046                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
    ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.jsonb_array_elements refno  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=100 width=32) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=2 loops=1)                                                                                                                |
          Output: jsonb_build_array(refno.value)                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
          Function Call: jsonb_array_elements('[{"Id": "0002222", "Type": "RefType"}, {"Id": "0002333", "Type": "RefType"}]'::jsonb)                                                                                                                      |
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.refs  (cost=0.00..885376.86 rows=1037818 width=486) (actual time=23793.829..23793.830 rows=0 loops=3)                                                                                                       |
        Output: 
        Filter: ((refs.json_data -> 'References'::text) @> ANY ($0))                                                                                                                                                              |
        Rows Removed by Filter: 8352299                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
        Buffers: shared hit=4220 read=609812 dirtied=75                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=61795.046                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
        Worker 0:  actual time=23793.628..23793.629 rows=0 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                                             |
          Buffers: shared hit=2002 read=202638 dirtied=6                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=20565.263                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
        Worker 1:  actual time=23784.348..23784.349 rows=0 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                                             |
          Buffers: shared hit=1059 read=202832 dirtied=69                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=20593.289                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
Settings: effective_cache_size = '2640112kB', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'                                                                                                                                                                          |
Query Identifier: 4447059927147613398                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
Planning:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
  Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
Planning Time: 0.286 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
Execution Time: 23807.719 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
```

Query plan after modified the query based on the inputs from Laurenz Albe:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Gather  (cost=1000.00..33199657.22 rows=26046052 width=518) (actual time=42826.145..42840.404 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                  |
  Output: refs.id, refs.json_data
  Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
  Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
  Buffers: shared hit=3048 read=610912 dirtied=2466                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=25028.306                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..30594052.02 rows=10852522 width=518) (actual time=42817.831..42821.316 rows=0 loops=3)                                                                                                                                          |
        Output: refs.id, refs.json_data
        Join Filter: ((refs.json_data  -> 'References'::text) @> jsonb_build_array(refNo.value))                                                                                                                                 
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8352160                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
        Buffers: shared hit=3048 read=610912 dirtied=2466                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=25028.306                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
        Worker 0:  actual time=42814.320..42814.322 rows=0 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                                             |
          Buffers: shared hit=1038 read=205719 dirtied=789                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=8403.926                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
        Worker 1:  actual time=42813.762..42813.765 rows=0 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                                             |
          Buffers: shared hit=1024 read=201674 dirtied=982                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
          I/O Timings: shared/local read=8412.231                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.refs  (cost=0.00..722485.22 rows=10852522 width=486) (actual time=0.962..19531.915 rows=8352160 loops=3)                                                                                              |
              Output: refs.id, refs.json_data
              Buffers: shared hit=3048 read=610912 dirtied=2466                                                                                                                                                                                                |
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=25028.306                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
              Worker 0:  actual time=0.817..19559.124 rows=8448451 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                                     |
                Buffers: shared hit=1038 read=205719 dirtied=789                                                                                                                                                                                               |
                I/O Timings: shared/local read=8403.926                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
              Worker 1:  actual time=0.834..19706.338 rows=8261642 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                                     |
                Buffers: shared hit=1024 read=201674 dirtied=982                                                                                                                                                                                               |
                I/O Timings: shared/local read=8412.231                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
        ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.jsonb_array_elements refno  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=100 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=25056480)                                                                                                     |
              Output: refno.value                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
              Function Call: jsonb_array_elements('[{"Id": "0001", "Type": "RefType"}]'::jsonb)                                                                                                                                                          |
              Worker 0:  actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=8448451                                                                                                                                                                                         |
              Worker 1:  actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=8261642                                                                                                                                                                                         |
Settings: effective_cache_size = '2640112kB', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'                                                                                                                                                                          |
Query Identifier: -5824741316160729696                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
Planning:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
  Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
Planning Time: 0.358 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
Execution Time: 42840.510 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
```

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN` plan for both queries.

Comment: Not just EXPLAIN, that's just a plan, always use `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get all the details about the plan and its execution.

Comment: Updated complete query plan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `@> ANY` won't use a GIN index.

Try to rewrite the query along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM refs
   JOIN (SELECT /* whatever you have in the ANY(ARRAY(...)) clause */) AS q(col)
      ON json_data -> 'References' @> q.col;
```

That has a chance of being processed as a nested loop join with an index scan on `refs` on the inner side.

Comment: Still not using the index

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Happens often if people store tables of structured data in a `jsonb`. With a different, normalized design the query would be fast and efficient. If you edited your question and posted the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` for your query, perhaps we could say more. You are not running your query on a table with five rows, are you? you need substantial amounts of data to test such things.

Comment: I have edited the question complete query plan and I am running the query with 25 million rows.

Comment: I see two potential problems: 1) PostgreSQL estimates that the result of `jsonb_array_elements()` is 100, which is far off the mark. you could improve that by using a `VALUES` statement instead, or you could write a custom table function with a different `ROWS` setting. 2) you may have forgotten to `ANALYZE refs` after creating the GIN index, so that PostgreSQL doesn't have the statistics it needs. In addition, you can play with `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` (reducing it) and `random_page_cost` (also reducing it) to see if you can get the index to be used.